# EXCEL: Unique fields but exclude if it contains the word 'Total'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to complete the following formula which allows me to find unique fields within  column but not include any that have the word 'Total' in it.

I have the following formula but doesn't work
`UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:B6,A1<>"*Total*"))`

Table

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| A | A |
| A Total | A |
| B | B |
| B Total | B |

Result

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | B |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:B6,NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Total",A1:A6)))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If you want to save a function: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:B6,ISERR(FIND("Total",A1:A6))))`

Comment: Pity I didn't think of it myself!